# Joint time series model of dividends and stock returns

Tags: dividends

Dividends on stocks are typically paid quarterly. Is there research on bivariate time series models of quarterly stock returns and dividends? Corporate management has discretion over dividends, and they are often unchanged or increased slightly, because investors dislike dividend cuts. When dividend cuts are made, they are often large. Stock dividends are positively correlated to lagged stock returns.

Two applications of time series models of stock returns and dividends are deciding whether to invest in stocks vs. dividend swaps and pricing long-term stock options.